# Rails: redirect_to 'myapp://' to call iOS app from mobile safari

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, redirect, mobile-safari

I have a native iOS app that can be called from Mobile Safari in iOS via `myiosapp://`. I also have a simple Rails app that SHOULD redirect to the native app when the request is coming from mobile. This is where I am I having problems - I can't `redirect_to 'myiosapp://`

I want to describe this problem as short as possible, so I made a sample app that shaves away the irrelevant information, but replicates the same problem.

Here's my routes.rb:

```
MyRailsApp::Application.routes.draw do
  root :to => 'redirect#index'
end
```

And here's redirect_controller.rb:

```
class RedirectController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if request_from_mobile?
      redirect_to "myiosapp://"
    else
      redirect_to "/default.html"
    end
  end

  private

  def request_from_mobile?
    request.user_agent =~ /Mobile|webOS/
  end
end
```

Whenever I run `rails server` and go to `localhost::3000`, I get this:

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-09-21 14:00:52 +0800
Processing by RedirectController#index as HTML
Redirected to motionapp://
Completed 302 Found in 0ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
[2012-09-21 14:00:52] ERROR URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(absolute but no path): motionapp://
    /Users/dev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/generic.rb:1202:in `rescue in merge'
    /Users/dev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/generic.rb:1199:in `merge'
    /Users/dev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:220:in `setup_header'
    /Users/dev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:150:in `send_response'
    /Users/dev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:110:in `run'
    /Users/dev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

Before posting this, I've already seen a number of similar problems, but none seemed to be more specific to how I can implement this in Rails:

[How to redirect from Mobile Safari to Native iOS app (like Quora)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9688319/how-to-redirect-from-mobile-safari-to-native-ios-app-like-quora)

[iphone web app to automatically redirect to app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182666/iphone-web-app-to-automatically-redirect-to-app)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out there's a simple solution that is enough for the context of my app as of the moment. I just needed to handle the redirect in javascript. Other solutions are still welcome. :)

```
<html><head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var userAgent = window.navigator.userAgent;
      if (userAgent.match(/iPad/i) || userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) {
        window.location = "myiosapp://"
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    Some html page
  </body>
</html>
```